# Inject data into component in Bootstrap Modal on Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap which adds Bootstrap components to Angular. You can inject components into an opened Modal, so the injected component makes up the body/content of the opened modal.

I have a list of `Player`. When I click a player, I want to open a Modal with the clicked player's data inside of it. I can open a Modal with the injected `PlayerComponent` like this.

```
constructor(
  private modalService: NgbModal
) { }

openPlayerModal() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PlayerComponent)
}
```

The question is... **How do I inject additional data to the component to let it know what player's data to fetch?** E.g. I might have an `OnInit` interface on the `PlayerComponent` that fetches data from an API based on an ID supplied by the `modalService.open()` call.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with that service: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.ts#L52 there isn't a parameter for additional data. The only way is to use a shared service it seems.

Comment: Isn't it possible to instantiate the component before passing it to the `open()` method?

Comment: It is possible if you are using `createComponent` and it's resolver to dynamically create a component but idk how that works with the library you are using.

Comment: I found a solution. Check it out below.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like `@ng-angular/ng-angular` allow you to touch the component instance after it has been instantiated. So you can then modify the values.

So solution would be:

```
constructor(
  private modalService: NgbModal
) { }

openPlayerModal() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PlayerComponent)
  modalRef.componentInstance.player_id = 1;
}
```

And then make the component use an `@Input()` decorator on `player_id`.

```
export class PlayerComponent {
  @Input() player_id;
  ...
}
```

Comment: seems to be correct solution rather than any work around like handling through route params